# dependency is not respected in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am dealing with a docker composer project. Here is the compose file :

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  tomcatserver:
    build: ./mavenServer
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8010:8080"
  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "tpformation"
      MYSQL_USER: "tomcat"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "tomcat" 
    expose:
      - "3306"
```

when I start my stack with docker-composer up, it is always the maven containers that starts first. However, it should be the db one. Could you help please.

Comment: Share the output of `docker compose up`.

Comment: Usually database containers are not actually available immediately after they start. `depends_on` makes sure the container is up, but it doesn't ensure it actually listens on any ports. You need to include some kind of health check, that will wait until the database is available, and then start your server.

Comment: I also faced the same issue recently( I am also learning docker). For temporary fix I did time.sleep(5) for the server so that DB can work. Would love to know how exactly it can be solved .

Answer (score 0):

Docker Compose used to have a `condition` configuration under `depends_on`. This is no longer the case.

From [this page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/):

> - depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until
>     they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see Controlling 
>     startup order for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.
> - Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on.

The simplest way to handle this issue, is to simply avoid it. Do `docker-compose up -d db` and then you can start and restart anything that depends on it (`docker-compose up tomcatserver`).

In most cases, dependencies normally "become healthy" before any other container needs them, so you can just `docker-compose up your-app` and never notice the issue.

Of course, all the above statements are valid assuming you are not using the same docker-compose in production.

If however, you are still interested in hardening the startup sequence, you can take a look at the [Control startup and shutdown order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) docker manual page, for some possibilities.

Relevant snippet from this page:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Personally, I recommend against such tricks wherever possible.